# freebsd Broadcom 4322 wireless card issue

Tags: wifi, freebsd, configuration, broadcom

I thought it would be fun to try out FreeBSD and had an old MacBook Pro (13 “ mid 2009) which I could screw around with. Everything was going pretty good until I tried to connect to my wifi network. I’ve got a Broadcom 4322 wifi card in the machine. After a bit of poking around the hand book, old mailing lists, Landon Fuller’s blog, Adrian Chadd’s blog and so on. I ascertained that it requires the bwn driver with the GPL options. I tethered my laptop to the internet using my phone and did the following things:

1) Make install cleaned the ports/net/bwn-firmware-kmod

2) In the makefile for the /sys/modules/bwn/Makefile I've uncommented the
 ".PATH: ${SRCTOP}/sys/gnu/dev/bwn/phy_n" and the "SRC+= if_bwn…" lines

3) recompiled the kernel with the "device bwn” line uncommented in the kernel config file and I added the “device firmware” line at this point as well (its now in there)

4) added the following to the /boot/loader.conf
If_bwn_load=“YES”
bwn_v4_ucode_load=“YES”
and then to be safe
bwn_v4_n_ucode_load=“YES”
bwn_v4_lp_ucode_load=“YES”

So the results of a dmesg | grep bwn: bwn0: bwn_phy_n_attach: BWN_GPL_PHY not in the kernel config; no PHY-N support

Now this is were it gets confusing for me:

I added the line
options BWN_GPL_PHY 
To the kernel config file and tried to recompile the kernel and it exits with an error in the linker saying that it can’t find the definitions for a number of nphy_op_ functions. I have however found the functions that it couldn’t link against in the if_bwn_phy_n_core.c file in the /sys/gnu/dev/bwn/phy_n directory so I am now somewhat confused.

Answer (score 0):

add BWN_DEBUG and BWN_GPL_PHY to your kernel config

FreeBSD 12 works as well without editing the driver source.
Cf. https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-wireless/2016-May/006738.html